# Powershell remoting with active directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am able to connect to domain controller via below scrip remotely, but after that i want to run `disable-ADAccount` ,`Get-ADUser` command but I am getting error

```
Get-ADUser : The server has rejected the client credentials.
```

How can I call active directory command in single script file?

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Lab\dcadmin", $password)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName dc-01 -Port 5985 -Credential $cred
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: On a computer joined to the domain in question, right-click on the Powershell Start Menu icon or shortcut and choose "Run as administrator". Enter the credentials of a Domain Administrator account. Then try the Powershell commands. They should run in the context of a Domain Administrator account and you should have no authorization problems.

Note, if you are logged on to the domain-joined computer with a local admin account, this might not work, because when you choose "Run as administrator" it will run it as a local administrator without prompting for credentials. Either log on to the computer as a user who is not an administrator or as a Domain Administrator.

Comment: :) Big thanks to you ..its working. can i hard-code this setting?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to code privilege elevation - which doesn't mean it's not possible, I just don't know. If you are scheduling this script or not running it manually in some way, then the scheduler or application that runs the script should have a way to elevate the shell. Are you aware of the *runas* command? That might help.

Comment: i got your point i can do this :)

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together.

Comment: Intermediate step: $Cred = Get-Credential ; Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 'dc-01' -Port 5985 -Credential $Cred # Just to see if it is the setting of credentials which goes wrong.